# Get last string from variable

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I created a script that other people will be using. Because of this, I am refactoring my code to use more variables. I have a variable named `$endcol` that will always be equal to the last string placed in another variable, `$columnsToExtract`. How can I make this work?

Right now my code is:

```
$columnsToExtract = '30', '31', '39'
$endcol = 39
```

Comment: You're kidding, don't you?   ;-)   `$columnsToExtract[-1]`

Comment: Wow... Too easy.

Comment: Very idiomatic: `$columnsToExtract | Select-Object -Last 1`

Comment: @beatcracker: The pipeline is an elegant tool, but not always the right one, especially when it comes to performance: compare `Measure-Command { 1..1e6 | Select-Object -Last 1 }` to  `Measure-Command { (1..1e6)[-1] }`

Comment: @mklement0 Yep, that's why it's a comment, not an answer. Should've mention performance issues, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get always the last element of an array you can use the "negativ index" starting with -1. Like this:

```
$columnsToExtract = '30', '31', '39'
$endcol = $columnsToExtract[-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$columntoextract = '30','31','39'
$endcol = $($columntoextract[2])
$endcol
```

Comment: What is when the array has less or more than 3 elements?  ;-)